# Indexing object element inside json array with Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a 9.4 Postgres database which has a table containing a `jsonb` field.

The structure of the json looks similar to this:

```
{
  name: 'customer1',
  age: 28,
  products: [{
    name: 'product1',
    price: 100
  }, {
    name: 'product2',
    price: 200
  }]
}
```

The following query returns the aforementioned json just fine:

```
SELECT jdoc
FROM customers, jsonb_array_elements(jdoc->'products') as products
WHERE (products->>'price')::numeric > 150
```

The problem is that the performance suffers quite a bit on bigger databases.

What index can I use to speed up this query?

---

What I've tried to far:

- `GIN` indices (both `jsonb_ops` and `jsonb_path_ops`). They only seem to work on existence operators like `@>` though.
- `CREATE INDEX ON persons(((jsonb_array_elements(jdoc->'products')->>'price')::numeric))`. Which give me give me datatype mismatch error.

  - Note that `CREATE INDEX ON persons(((jdoc->'age')::numeric))` works and allows me to query `(jdoc->>'age')::numeric < 30` fast.

Comment: Use relational data model instead of JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a function and use that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION max_price(jsonb) RETURNS double precision
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$SELECT max(p.price)
FROM jsonb_to_recordset($1->'products')
        AS p(name text, price double precision)$$;

CREATE INDEX customers_ind ON customers(max_price(jdoc));
```

Then this index can be used with a query like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT jdoc FROM customers WHERE max_price(jdoc) > 150;

                                   QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using customers_ind on customers  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=36)
   Index Cond: (max_price(jdoc) > '150'::double precision)
(2 rows)
```

This is not your query, but it should be equivalent.

Comment: But this means I also have to create a second function/index that uses `min(p.price)` if I want to query for a price less than a value. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. This targets just the special case in your question. The answer should give you the idea how a problem like yours might be tackled.

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait a day or two to see if there are other options before accepting.